# Capture a regex match for replacement from lookup table

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm writing a language interpreter in PowerShell (the language is PILOT, for those who might be interested), and I've gotten to the point where I'm implementing variable replacement.  A variable name consists of either a `$` or a `#`, followed by up to ten characters in the set `[A-Za-z0-9]`. However, if the variable name is prefixed by a `\`, it should *not* be replaced.  As near as I can figure, the pattern I'm looking to match is `[^\\][\$#]\w{,10}`, but I'm not clear on how to store the result of the match in a PowerShell variable so that I can look up the variable name in a table to replace it with its value.

For example, if the powershell variable `$expr` contains the string `\#Foo has the value #Foo`, and `$vartable["#Foo"]` contains the value `5`, I would need to capture `#Foo` - the second one only - in $varname, and then do a replace of the captured `#Foo` with $vartable[$varname] - `$expr -replace "[^\\][\$#]\w{,10}",$vartable[$varname]` should yield `\#Foo has the value 5`.

Have I correctly calculated the pattern, and how do I capture the match?

(I should note that I'm developing this with PowerShell 5.1, but expect it to be able to run in that version or anything later, including PSCore on non-Windows OSes.)

Comment: `[^\\]` is not a valid way to check if a char is escaped or not, since the backslash may be also escaped. I.e. `\#Foo` has a var that must be matched. Is it so here? Then, the valid way is to use `(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)`.

Comment: Then, you cannot use code inside a string replacement pattern, use `[regex]::Replace($s,'(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)[$#]\w{1,10}\b', {param($match) $vartable[$match.Value] })`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - No, if the string contains `\#FOO`, I _don't_ want it replaced; the backslash more-or-less signals that I want the variable name as a literal to remain in the string - for example, `\#FOO is #FOO` should, if #FOO is in the variable table with the value 5, end up after processing as `\#FOO is 5`.

Comment: Then use `'(?<!\\)[$#]\w{1,10}\b'`. BTW, I meant `\\$Foo`, sorry for not adding the second backslash, I meant that if you escape something with ``\`` the literal backslashes are usually escaped with the second backslash.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Do I not have to escape the `$`? I thought that was the EOL anchor?

Comment: If you use it inside a single quoted literal you do not need to escape it inside a character class for sure. In a double quoted literal, you might want to escape `$` when it can be parsed as a start of a variable.

Comment: In PowerShell Core v6.1.0+ and newer, I'd recommend `$s -replace '(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)[$#]\w{1,10}\b', { $vartable[$_.Value] }`. If it works for you please let know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^\\]` pattern is *usually* not a valid way to check if a char is escaped or not since the backslash may be also escaped to denote a literal backslash char. For example, `\\#Foo` has an unescaped variable that must be matched as per the original requirements. The valid way is to use `(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)` .NET compliant lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with any amount of even backslashes not preceded with a backslash.

Next, you cannot use code inside a string replacement pattern. You may either use a callback inside `[regex]::Replace` or - starting with PowerShell Core v6.1 - you may use a script block as the replacement argument for `-replace`:

```
[regex]::Replace($s,'(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)[$#]\w{1,10}\b', {param($match) $vartable[$match.Value] })
```

or (PowerShell Core v6.1+):

```
$s -replace '(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)[$#]\w{1,10}\b', { $vartable[$_.Value] }
```

Comment: See the edit to the question; I'm doing this on 5.1, and expect it to run on that or later.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Use `[regex]::Replace($s,'(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)[$#]\w{1,10}\b', {param($match) $vartable[$match.Value] })`

Comment: In a test string of `\\\$foo $foo \#foo #foo`, this seems to delete all occurrences of `$foo`, and replace the 'unescaped' `#foo` with the value. It does the same regardless of the order of the `$foo`s and `#foo`s.

Comment: Wait... It seems to make a difference if `$s` is defined with `'` or `"`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin In a `\\\$foo $foo \#foo #foo` *string*, the second and fourth words are matched. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3c!%5c%5c%29%28%3f%3a%5c%5c%7b2%7d%29*%29%5b%24%23%5d%5cw%7b1%2c10%7d%5cb&i=%5c%5c%5c%24foo+%24foo+%5c%23foo+%23foo&r=). You must use single quoted literals to avoid string interpolation.

Comment: The `[RegEx]::Replace...` technique works for me, with a slight modification due to an issue not related to the regex _per se_, only with the way I have to format the value in `$vartable[]`. Thank you!