# Powershell Extract Distinguished Name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to extract the element from my Distinguished Name into array,and except the DC elemnet.

for exemple :"CN=TestGroup,OU=Groups,OU=UT-SLC,OU=US,DC=Company,DC=com"

I need to have array like below

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| CN | TestGroup |
| OU | Groups |
| OU | UT-SLC |
| OU | US |

Can someone help me?

Comment: `'CN=TestGroup,OU=Groups,OU=UT-SLC,OU=US,DC=Company,DC=com' -Split ',' |ConvertFrom-StringData`

Comment: @iRon DNs can contain escaped commas `\,` in some odd cases. `'CN=Test\, Group,OU=Groups,OU=UT-SLC,OU=US,DC=Company,DC=com' -split '(?<!\\),' |ConvertFrom-StringData` works nice for those cases.

Comment: @Santiago, has a point. But if we going to look deeper into this anyways. You also want to take care of the situation where a name ends with a backslash (escaped: `Name\\ `) where the following comma (`,`) is a valid separator. See: [(PowerShell) split string with escaped separator characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22249126/1701026) 

Comment: @iRon thanks for that one, I'll save it on my bookmarks hehe

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this what you are looking for, please check it

```
$x= "CN=TestGroup,OU=Groups,OU=UT-SLC,OU=US,DC=Company,DC=com"
$y = $x.Split(',')
$z = foreach ($line in $y){
[pscustomobject]@{Name = $line.Split('=')[0]; Value=$line.Split('=')[1]}
}
$z | where {$_.name -ne "DC"}
```

Comment: Nice, but as  @Olaf mentioned user should submit his code, either working or not, to help him instead of giving him the answer like that.

Comment: yes sorry, but i don't have enough votes to comment on his post to direct him the correct way

Comment: According to his history on SO he seems not interested in a dialog ... he seems to never answer to comments or even answers.

Comment: @olaf, yes you are right

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).