# How to get-adgroup members by their Name or SamAccountName

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i would like to extract members from an AD Group that contains Members and security group.

> ```
> Example, Group_A:
> User1
> User2
> User3
> Group_B
> ```

When I run my script, it shows:

> CN=User1,OU=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com
> CN=User2,OU=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com
> CN=User3,OU=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com
> CN=Group_B,OU=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com

Is there another way to show their Name and/or SamAccountname?

```
$Groups = 
@"
GroupNames;
Group_A
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'



$ADGroups = 
Foreach ($Group in $Groups){ 
Get-ADGroup $Group.GroupNames -Server contoso.com -Properties Members }

$ADGroups.Members
```

Comment: You seem to have a input file where users and groups are mixed in a strange way.. This doesn't look like a csv file at all, where group names should be put in their own column. Please open to that file in notepad and copy the first 3 or 4 lines. Then edit your question and paste it in there as formatted text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other helpful answers show, if you want to play safe, you can use [`Get-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to get the group membership, this would also be useful because you would be able to distinguish the `ObjectClass` of each member.

You could also do string manipulation over the elements (`distinguishedName`) of the `member` attribute of the AD Group by following [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782505/powershell-split-string-with-escaped-separator-characters).

**If the members of the group are on different Domains**, this should work however it would be quite slow most likely.

```
foreach($group in $groups) {
    $membership = Get-ADGroup $Group -Properties Member
    $membership.Member | Group-Object { ($_ -split '(?=DC=)',2)[1] } |
    ForEach-Object {
        [adsi]$ldap = 'LDAP://{0}' -f $_.Name
        [string]$domain = $ldap.Name

        foreach($member in $_.Group) {
            $obj = Get-ADObject $member -Server $domain
            [pscustomobject]@{
                MemberOf       = $membership.Name
                Domain         = $domain
                SamAccountName = $obj.SamAccountName
                ObjectClass    = $obj.ObjectClass
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just asking for clarification because I actually really don't know: In this usecase, is there a point to use get-adgroup? Since the OP wants the members only, is it not safe enough to use Get-ADGroupmember directly, since they both use the parameter "idendity", which is unique in both usecases?

Comment: @Bowshock No you're totally right, there is no need for `Get-ADGroup` in this case. As long as identity is a valid sam / upn / dn etc.

Comment: I think you're right. I do have nested groups though. Is this in good practice?

Comment: you might find [this function](https://github.com/santysq/Get-Hierarchy) I made for display group hierarchy @ak2595

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon If I have a user from another domain in this group it doesnt work. i have a trusted domain with all rights

Comment: @ak2595 i have updated on what could be done if the members are on different domains, it will likely be pretty slow but I think should work

Answer (score 1):

Get-ADGroupMember has two parameters you can use for that. samaccountname, and name.

Simply do the following:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity $ADGroup | select-object SamAccountName, Name
```

Or in your code snippet:

```
Foreach ($group in $groups) {
Get-AdGroup -identity $group | select-object Samaccountname, Name }
```

Of course you could add:

```
Get-AdGroup -identity $group | select-object Samaccountname, Name | export-csv C:\mypath\report.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run a query against the returned values using `Get-ADObject` since it accepts *DistinguishedNames* as a value and isn't limited by object class:

```
foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{ 
    (Get-ADGroup $Group.GroupNames -Server contoso.com -Properties Members).Members | 
        ForEach-Object -Process {
            Get-ADObject -Identity $_ -Properties DisplayName | Select-Object -Property DisplayName
        }     
}
```

...or, you can split the results at the desired entry:

```
foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{ 
    (Get-ADGroup $Group.GroupNames -Server contoso.com -Properties Members).Members | 
        ForEach-Object -Process {
            $_.Split(',',2).Split("=")[1]
        }     
}
```

---

**Disclaimer**: *I don't have the AD Module installed on my system so I can't confirm if this is all that is needed*.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to expand the *members* property and in `Get-ADGroup` and then pipe it to `Get-ADUser`

```
$adUsers = Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Get-ADGroup $Group.GroupNames -Server contoso.com -Properties Members | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members | Get-aduser
}
```

Comment: The problem is the fact that I also have users from another domain in this group... it will show only users from the current domain