# Powershell - Active Directory - split DistinguishedName

Tags: powershell, split, active-directory

I need the marked part bellow of the distinguished name of an computer:

```
CN=X, OU=EXAMPLEOU, OU=D, DC=A, DC=B, DC=C
```

I just need `OU=EXAMPLEOU`.

How I get this part of the distinguished name:

```
$OU = Get-ADComputer -Identity $env:computername -Properties * | select @{N="OU";E={$_.DistinguishedName.Split(',')[-5].split('=')[1]}}
```

The output is:

```
OU
___
EXAMPLEOU
```

BUT I want the endresult to be a string that just returns `EXAMPLEOU`.

How can I do that? THANK YOU!

Comment: I'm guessting `OU=X` is actually `CN=X` isn't it?

Comment: I would recommend you to use the regex from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782505/powershell-split-string-with-escaped-separator-characters to answer your question, you just need to use dot notation, `$ou.ou`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Select`. Just wrap the `Get-ADComputer` command in parentheses and use it like an object.

I would also suggest not using `-Properties *` since that will get all of the attributes when you only need one. So just tell it which one you need and you'll save time and bandwidth.

So it would look like this:

```
$OU = (Get-ADComputer -Identity $env:computername -Properties DistinguishedName).DistinguishedName.Split(',')[-5].split('=')[1]
```